# RegistryKey.CreateSubKey throws IOException randomly

Tags: c#, registry

We have an application deployed in the office, and, on only one out of fifteen machines, it will *sometimes* throw a `System.IO.IOException` with the message `An internal error occurred.` at this piece of code.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
    @"Software\ABC Company Name Here\Apps\MyApp\Settings\",
    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
```

Msdn says this means

```
The nesting level exceeds 510.
-or-
A system error occurred, such as deletion of the key, or an attempt to create a key in the LocalMachine root.
```

Though neither seems to be the case. How would I track this down?

EDIT:

This is windows 7 and the user account is an administrator of the machine. We use the same setup in the entire office and only this one machine fails. Also it fails sporadically, the code works ~95% of the time.

Comment: Seems like a case of permissions to me.

Comment: What version of Windows? Does it fail when it has Admin rights?

Comment: Edited to describe the situation a little better. Also a permissions issue should throw a SecurityException, not an IOException